# SQL - Heterogeneous queries error with zabbix item

Tags: sql, zabbix

In Zabbix, There is no way to `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON` and `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` in the query section. At least isn't working. Is there any other way to set it?

I tried `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; SET ANSI_NULLS ON; select * ...` before the select statement and it did not work. I also tried `GO SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; ANSI_NULLS ON; select * ... GO` but that did not work either - Zabbix reported syntax error.

Error: Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection.

Here is my Query:

```
select sum(item_count) from (select  
coalesce(c.cnt, 0) as [item_count] 


from LINKED_DB_USER.[UserDB].[dbo].[User] as us LEFT JOIN LINKED_DB_USER.[USerDB].[dbo].[Account] as cs ON us.[user_id] = cs.[user_id]  

FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
 select [Account_ID], count(*) as cnt
from [OnlineUsers2].[dbo].[USER_NAME] where USER_ID in (select USER_ID from [OnlineUsers].[dbo].[Last_Login])
group by [Account_ID]
)  c on c.[Account_ID] = us.[Unique_ID] where cs.name = 'SOME_NAME') src;
```

Here is a screenshot of the item in zabbix.

[Zabbix_ITEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVMRG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, because `SET ...` is not supported by the underlying ODBC driver.

You cannot use that in isql too. Example:

```
SQL> SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
[S1000][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute
```

Howerver, did you try using a stored procedure?